# How minimize working time costs during work with old WinForms project?

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

My main goal is minimize working time costs during work with old WinForms project. I have made an example with realisation MCV + WinForms. It worked. I have got the clear model, but I have two methods in Controller.cs (OnSuper() and WorkMethod()) - and I can't like them. They don't carry functionality, but they have look when somebody spread butter on butter without bread. How can I upgrade this idea without interface as at MPV and without WPF?  Or is it not a good approach and I must create a new WPF project?

Class Model.cs

```
class Model
{    
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int R { get; set; }
    public Model() { }
    public Model(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
    public int GetRes()
    {
        return X + Y;            
    }
}
```

class Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        button1.Click += delegate
        {
            Controller controller = new Controller
            (
                this, 
                Int32.Parse(this.textBox1.Text),
                Int32.Parse(this.textBox2.Text)
            );
            controller.SuperEvent += Controller_SuperEvent;
            controller.OnSuper();
        };
    }
    private void Controller_SuperEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Controller controller = sender as Controller;
        textBox3.Text = controller.WorkMethod();
        controller.WorkMethod();
    }
}
```

and class Controller.cs

```
class Controller
{        
    public event EventHandler SuperEvent;
    Model model;
    Form1 form1;
    public int Result { get; set; }
    public int CX { get; set; }
    public int CY { get; set; }
    public Controller(Form1 form1, int cX, int cY)
    {
        this.form1 = form1;
        this.model = new Model();            
        CX = cX;
        CY = cY;
    }
    public void OnSuper()
    {
        SuperEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public string WorkMethod()
    {            
        model.X = CX;
        model.Y = CY;
        return model.GetRes().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: If it looks like the code is pointless then you're doing it right.  The point of the MVC pattern is to write code that is easy to maintain.  Expectation is that it no longer looks pointless ten years from now, but you can't predict the future.  Lots of MVC frameworks for Winforms around btw, do look at them before cooking your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make maintainability simpler draw clear line between layers responsibilities.

Model responsible for business logic

```
class Model
{    
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Model() {}

    public int GetRes() => X + Y
}
```

ViewModel responsible for preparing data for displaying in the view(if required) and for invoking model's business logic operation requested from the view.
`INotifyPropertyChanged` will notify view about possible changes without viewmodel being depended on concrete view type.

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{    
    private readonly Model _model;

    public int X { get; set; }

    public int Y { get; set; }

    private string _result = "";
    public string Result 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _result;
        } 

        private set
        {
            if (_result.Equals(value) == false)
            {
                _result = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }

        }
    }

    public ViewModel(Model model) => _model = model;

    public void CalculateResult()
    {
         Result = _model.GetRes().ToString();
    }

    // Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

View, which responsibility is to display values from viewmodel or call viewmodel operation when user requests.

```
public partial class View : Form
{    
    private ViewModel _viewmodel;

    public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
        var model = new Model { X = 10, Y = 20 }  
        _viewmodel = new ViewModel(model);

        // Bind controls to the viewmodel
        textboxForX.DataBindings.Add("Text", _viewmodel, "X", true);
        textboxForY.DataBindings.Add("Text", _viewmodel, "Y", true);
        labelForResult.DataBindings.Add("Text", _viewmodel, "Result", true);            
    } 

    private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EvetnArgs e)
    {
        _viewmodel.Calculate();
    }
}
```

Notice that in simple cases(as above) you can skip viewmodel "layer" and bind view straight to the model. But having a "buffer" between view and business logic will make your life easier when project starts grow.